# How to hot encode features preferably with a code example

Tags: python, pyspark, analytics, data-science

I have a data frame like this 

 **CODE | TYPE**  

0001 | A

0001 | B

0001 | C

0002 | A

0003 | B

....

and need to transform it to the following

 
**CODE | TYPE_A  | TYPE_B  | TYPE_C**

0001 | 1       |    1    |   1   
0002 | 1       |    0    |   0
0003 | 0       |    1    |   0

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the get_dummies function from pandas. Dummy variables are just another way of saying on-hot-encoding.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE': ['0001', '0001', '0001', '0002','0003'], 
                   'TYPE': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']})
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['TYPE'])
```

The `columns` argument let's you specify the columns you want to one-hot-encode.

This will give:

```
   CODE  TYPE_A  TYPE_B  TYPE_C
0  0001       1       0       0
1  0001       0       1       0
2  0001       0       0       1
3  0002       1       0       0
4  0003       0       1       0
```

Comment: see updated answer, you can add the `columns` argument